# How to speed up loop used for iterating over rows to find matching ID numbers and extract the data from it

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, analysis

I am using a function to use list comprehension to iterate through rows to compare ids. Next, it will extract the relevant columns from one dataframe to another dataframe to assign the data to a new column. Specifically, I am using the Airbnb Boston dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/airbnb/boston and the dataframe has data such as Neighbourhoods from the listings df to the calendar_df.

I filtered only ids that exist in both dataframes to prevent the code-breaking then filtered each id from the calendar df to reference the listing dataframe then copy the selected row back to a new column. The code works but it takes roughly 5 minutes or more to iterate over 1.3m rows. I've heard of NumPy and vectorized functions but I have no idea how to do that with my current code. Here is my function:

```
# function to copy data between dataframes
def append_df(df_org, df_dest, col, file_name):

"""Readme: For each id copy and append selected data from row to another df column then save to csv. 

*args descriptions:

df_org = origin df where data is gathered from as soon as the id is matched
df_dest = destination df where selected data from df_org is appended to a new column 'col'
col = name for the selected column for the data being copied over as a string in quotes
file_name = csv output file name as a string in quotes
"""

# silence the SettingWithCopyWarning
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'

# count each row
counter = -1

# creating an empty list for neighbourhood strings
area_list = []

for i in range(len(df_dest)):
    
    # add +1 for each row looped
    counter +=1
    
    # result is the value extracted from each row of the target column
    result = df_org[col][df_org['id'] == df_dest['listing_id'].iloc[i]].iloc[0]
    
    # display the listing_id for each operation
    id_count = df_org['id'][df_org['id'] == df_dest['listing_id'].iloc[i]].iloc[0]
    
    # display the listing_id for each operation
    area_list.append(result)
    
    # append the result values to the empty list variable
    progress = round(np.multiply(np.divide(counter, len(df_dest)), 100), 2)
    
     # create a % progress counter
    print(counter, id_count, result, progress, '%')

# write list to new column and save df to csv
df_dest[col] = area_list
df_dest.to_csv(file_name, index=False)

# calling our function
append_df(bos_list, bos_cal_match, 'neighbourhood', 'boston_calendar_test.csv')
```

Comment: Fix indentation please.

Comment: Which part do you mean?